# Commons Pooling: How to instantiate a concrete pool?

Tags: java, apache, pooling, apache-commons-pool

I've added commons-pooling-1.6.jar to my classpath and trying to instantiate a `StackObjectPool` and am failing at every turn:

```
// Deprecated.
ObjectPool<T> oPool = new StackObjectPool<T>();

// Error: Cannot instantiate the type BasePoolableObjectFactory<T>.
PoolableObjectFactory<T> oFact = new BasePoolableObjectFactory<T>();
ObjectPool<T> oPool = new StackObjectPool<T>(oFact);
```

Is this a deprecated API altogether? If so, what are some open source alternatives to Commons Pooling? Else, how do I instantiate a `StackObjectPool`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write your own Factory possibly extending BasePoolableObjectFactory. See here for more information: http://commons.apache.org/pool/examples.html

Below is a PoolableObjectFactory implementation that creates StringBuffers:

```
import org.apache.commons.pool.BasePoolableObjectFactory; 

public class StringBufferFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<StringBuffer> { 
    // for makeObject we'll simply return a new buffer 
    public StringBuffer makeObject() { 
        return new StringBuffer(); 
    } 

    // when an object is returned to the pool,  
    // we'll clear it out 
    public void passivateObject(StringBuffer buf) { 
        buf.setLength(0); 
    } 

    // for all other methods, the no-op  
    // implementation in BasePoolableObjectFactory 
    // will suffice 
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
new StackObjectPool<StringBuffer>(new StringBufferFactory())
```

Answer (score 1):

Most libraries have input focuses on an **object factory**. This tells to the pool how  create a new object when this is needed. E.g. for a pool of connections, all these are connected to the same database with the *same configuration*, like *user*, *password*, *url*, *driver*.

Need to create a concrete factory extending [`BasePoolableObjectFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/BasePoolableObjectFactory.html) class and write the method [`makeObject`](http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory.html#makeObject%28%29), as shown in the following example.

```
static class MyObject {
    private String config;

    public MyObject(String config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

static class MyFactory extends BasePoolableObjectFactory<MyObject> {

    public String config;

    public MyFactory(String config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject makeObject() throws Exception {
        return new MyObject(config);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFactory factory = new MyFactory("config parameters");
    StackObjectPool<MyObject> pool = new StackObjectPool<>(factory);
}
```

Swaranga Sarma has codified a very interesting example. See it at [*The Java HotSpot: A Generic and Concurrent Object Pool*](http://javawithswaranga.blogspot.mx/2011/10/generic-and-concurrent-object-pool.html)

Comment: I was going to complain about the use of 'codified' to denote 'has coded an implementation of', but having read that article, I think the term 'codified' is very appropriate!